# create a custom link with variables from a form

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

I have html form with 32 required fields , I want submit button to redirect the user to custom link uses the 32 fields .

php code :

```
$v1 = $_GET['1'] ;
$v2 = $_GET['2'] ;
$v3 = $_GET['3'] ;
$v4 = $_GET['4'] ;
$v5 = $_GET['5'] ;
...
..
..
.
$v32 = $_GET['32'] ;
```

html code :

```
<form action="" method="get">
            <hr>
            <h5>1</h5>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="1">* 1</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control border"
                            name="1" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="2">2</label>
                        <select name="2" class="form-control border">
                            <option value="a">A</option>
                            <option value="b">B</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="3">3</label>
                        <input type="text" name="3" class="form-control border"
                            value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
....
..
..
.
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="32">32</label>
                        <input type="text" name="32" class="form-control border"
                            value="">
                    </div>
                </div> </form>
```

i want the link to be like this :
https:// example.com/AA/file.php?1=$v1&2=$v2&3=$v3&4=$v4&......&32=$v32

Thank you

Comment: I don't get it, a GET form will redirect the user to an URL with parameters corresponding to input that was submitted in the form. So if you submitted with an input with a name 1 and a value $1, you will have a ?1=$v1.

Comment: if my input in name="1" is ABCD the link should be 1=ABCD&2=......

Comment: In your example ABCD is the value of the input ?

Comment: yes sir what ever user type in the placeholder should be in the link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<form action="file.php" method="get">
    <input name="1" type="text" value="" />
    <input name="2" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will redirect the user to file.php?1=here_user_input_value&2=here_user_input_value when submitting the form.